# UK landing interview

Tags: uk, student-visas, interview

About six months ago I entered the UK the second time on my visitor visa which I've already used once. In my landing interview, the border staff asked how many days I've stayed in the UK for my last visit. I answered X days (but in fact I stayed less than X days), and only realised that I answered it wrong after the landing interview. It was because the last visit was so long ago that I didn't remember that clearly. But during the interview, the staff didn't say anything; everything was quite smooth. I worry if this would affect my future visa application since in theory I should have given accurate information?

Comment: Understaying is better than overstaying 

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about it. The Border officer obviously didn’t have a problem with your answer. Many people might not readily remember exactly how many days they spent somewhere when put on the spot in such a situation. The important thing will be to be accurate in your visa application.

Answer (score 2):

No, this will not in any way hinder any future visa applications, understaying for any reason is not frowned upon by any country immigration. Overstaying however, even though not overstaying your visa permutations can sometimes bring some issues, I met that first hand in Vietnam a few years ago where I stated I was staying X days but instead ended up staying Y days which was till within my visa allowance but on exit the immigrations lectured me about it

Comment: I agree that understaying is not a problem, but in my case I was asked how long my previous visit was, not how long I will stay. It is because my previous visit was so long ago that I didn't remember the number of days I have spent, and gave a wrong answer when I re-enter the UK, so a little worried on whether this will be treated as giving false information.

Comment: Most likely not, humans get nervous and forget simple things like this, if you had forgotten to mention a 5 year jail sentence it would be difference but I would nit worry about this at all, I have many times when asked just made a hunch on last trips and never had issues